# Processes in Operating Systems

Tags: process, operating-system

When I read a source about the processes and threads in the operating system, I faced this sentence and it sounded weird to me:

`When a program is executed and handled by the processor, it converts into a process. A process needs to use the data and code segment in the memory.`

I think the first sentence is true naturally. However, I cannot understand why the process needs to use solely data and code segment?

```
#include <stdio.h>
x = 10;
y;

int main(void){

   int *array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
   printf("x and y are %d %d", x, y);

   return 0;
}
```

I think that when this code is executed, the generated process use bss, data, heap and code segment. In my opinion, a process can benefit from any segment of the memory.

If my thoughts are wrong, can anyone explain the reason ?

Comment: What book are you reading?

Comment: This is actually not a book. These sentences are written in presentations of my university.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A process has to store in memory:

- Code.
- Heap.
- Stack.
- Data.
- BSS.

Except for really trivial ones, **a program will use all these segments**. Take a look at [wikipedia's explanation of what the segments contain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment).

I think in the sentence the author didn't want to go into details and refers to Stack/Heap/Data/BSS as the data of your program, not the actual data segment.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is not correct.

> When a program is executed and handled by the processor, it converts into a process. A process needs to use the data and code segment in the memory.

A process has to exist before a program can be executed. On many non-eunuch's systems a single process runs multiple program.s

> I think that when this code is executed, the generated process use bss, data, heap and code segment. In my opinion, a process can benefit from any segment of the memory.

The LINKER deine program segments. The loader follows the instructions of the linker to create the address space.

"bss, data, heap, and code" is a bad way to envision the address space.

There is:

1. Executable data
2. Read only data
3. Read/write data that can be

   - initialized
   - uninitialized

Heap and stack are just read/write data. The operating system cannot even tell what data is stack and what is heap. It's all just memory.

Comment: "When a program is executed and handled by the processor, it converts into a process." I thought this sentence was true because there is a sentence in the book "Modern Operating Systems Andrew Tanenbaum" : "A program is something that may be stored in the disk, not doing anything. A process is an activity of some kind." There is also good analogy in the book which implies that the food recipe is a program whereas the process is the activity of baking the cake via the recipe. In this case, how does process exist before the the program is executed ?

Comment: One some systems a user always has a process that contains a command interpreter that sits in the background. The command interpreter runs programs in that process. In eunuchs variants, you get a process with a program already loaded, then reload another program.